# Biblical era gesture signifying peace between two parties?

Tags: history, old-testament, new-testament, historic-customs

I am working on a painting set in the Biblical era which shows a military group confronting another group.

I am trying to find a gesture which the leader of one army would make to indicate that they are at peace with, or have peaceful intentions toward the other party.

Does anyone know of anything like that?

Specifically I am thinking of a gesture which would be understood this way in the first century, but a gesture from previous biblical eras would probably also work.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Christianity.

Comment: I'd suggest the question be asked on, or migrated to, the [History Stackexchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/) site. I concur with its closure here.

Comment: Already asked on History.SE: [First Century (or earlier) gesture signifying peace between two parties?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/37614/12795)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did ask this in the History.SE and have received a good response. SE doesn't seem to let me remove this question myself for some reason, so moderators feel free to remove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typically in the Old Testament, they would send emissaries to negotiate covenants with their enemies.

> Luke 14:31-32 "Or what king, when he sets out to meet another king in battle, will not first sit down and consider whether he is strong enough with ten thousand men to encounter the one coming against him with twenty thousand? "Or else, while the other is still far away, he sends a delegation and asks for terms of peace.

Other references:  Josh 9:6, 2 Samuel 3:12-13, 1 Kings 15:19, 2 Kings 18:23, Genesis 23:8-9, and others.